# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date'

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on a script for Google research but I have no previous experience using pandas.

I have been following a tutorial and written material to complete this but this part of my code doesn't seem to be working(maybe outdated syntax).

**The error that I get is AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date':**

```
def get_search_console_data(webproperty, days=-365):
  if webproperty is not None:
    query = webproperty.query.range(start='today', days=days).dimension('date', 'query')
    r = query.get()
    df = pd.DataFrame(r.rows)
    return df

  print("Web property doesn't exist, please select a valid one from this list")
  print(account.webproperties)

df = get_search_console_data(webproperty)
     

    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

    df[df["date"] > "2021-10-3"]

last_day_queries = df[df["date"] > "2021-10-3"]["query"]
rest_of_queries = df[df["date"] < "2021-10-3"]["query"]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Only date here is in df. My best guess (without a minimal example) is that your function get_search_console_data returns None for some reason. Can you check the value of df ?

Comment: Hey, I have updated my question with more code but I don't seem to find any issues, maybe it's just my little knowledge about the library

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError%3A+%27NoneType%27+object+has+no+attribute -- question is not what causes the error but why you have `None` there. As a new user here, make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `webproperty` appears to be `None`, which causes `get_search_console_data` to return `None`. You should probably raise an exception if `webproperty` is `None`, as well as take care to avoid passing `None` as an argument in the first place.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the feedback, any idea how this could be done since this is not my code?

Comment: Try looking here: https://www.reddit.com/r/CodingHelp/